# Regex - Match Numeric values but not Date

Tags: regex, date, numeric

I want to match numeric values, `integer`, `float` but not `date` values.

```
123                      - match
1.23                     - match
12345678.99              - match 
2020-07-30 10:09:25.786  - no match 
2020-07-30               - no match 
2020/07/30               - no match
```

etc

Currently I can match numeric but it takes also the first part of the dates. How can exclude when there are characters (except the decimal place)

`([0-9._]+)`

Comment: What is your regex platform?

Comment: What kind of datetime formats you need to support?

Comment: See `(?<!\d)\d{4}([ \/-])\d{2}\1\d{2}(?: \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:[.,]\d+)?)?(?!\d)(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJgg44/1).

Comment: For your examples perhaps `(?<!\S)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/3fX6Yq/1

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<!\d|/|-|\.|,)\d{1,}(?:\.\d{,2})?(?!\d|/|-|\.|,|:)
```

This regex should meet your requirements.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yff0yh/1/)

Answer (score -1):

try this regex it solve your issue: `[0-9]+[-:\/].+|([0-9._]+)`

Here is the Regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/GDHYsb/2

Comment: (Re)read the question: `I want to match numeric values, integer, float but not date values`

Comment: Please see the demo my regex gives you the desired result at Group 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
^\d+(?:[.]\d+)*$
```

You could use above regex.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jq6FuW/1)

Comment: This will match `2020.07.30`

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. My regex is based on date format types. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41183_01/DR/Date_Format_Types.html

Comment: Where have you seen the question is about oracle date format? `2020.07.30` is a perfectly valid date format, at least it's really not a valid number (float or integer) and your regex gives a match and it shouldn't.

Comment: I do not deny YYYY.MM.DD which is a valid date format. Thank you for your indication. We will return the request of this author. In this context, this author said: "How can exclude when there are characters (except the decimal place)". So my regex only covered this request.